Website slows down and Error 522
I am the web admin of an eCommerce site hosted on Digital Ocean using LEMP stack, with CloudFlare as CDN. Everything went well for months but suddenly just now all the operations slow to a crawl, backend and frontend. The plugin page that usually loads in few seconds now taking more than 10 seconds to load. Same for other pages. It then showed that it is Error 522.
Below are something I have tried:

Disabled all the plugins and reverted to default theme
Raised the memory limit in wp_config.php as follows:

define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M' );
define( 'MAX_WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '2048M' );

Raised the memory_limit in php.ini to 1024M
CPU, RAM and disk usage are well below 100%
Set as Development mode in Cloudflare
Check with Query Monitor plugin. No slow query, just some deprecated php warnings
php error log only has slow query tracking
nginx error log has no fatal error

Anything I can do to troubleshoot the issue? Thanks

That's a problem with the connection between your web server and Cloudflare. It's not specific to WordPress so it would be a better fit for a different Stack.

Is your site slow if you load it directly, not through the CDN?

Yes it loads even slower if I enabled development mode in Cloudflare.

Update: The php slow log shows that nginx-helper plugin is taking long time to purge the data when I was creating woocommerce order. Everything seems to be back to normal after I disabled it. Not sure why it happened as I didn't update the plugin recently but I did update Wordpress and WooCommerce plugins.

Great, good job diagnosing it! I'd report this to the nginx-helper plugin support forum then, or their GitHub issues.

Actually no, something very wrong is happening. At first glance Nginx-helper just clears Nginx's cache when a post is published. But you're saying that the site is slow in general, not when you're adding new products? And in any case a cache-clean should be asynchronous and instant: is the delay actually rebuilding cached content you've just deleted? Can you look at cache statistics and see exactly what's going on with the cache?

It's possible that 1) nginx-helper is getting triggered for post-type entities that aren't really site visible, e.g. new orders (if they're posts in WooCommerce?); and 2) it's deleting all content and not just content that needed to be regenerated, which seems wrong - it ought to be cleverer than that? However if it's just completely broken with WooCommerce then someone should have noticed by now, there are enough contributors to it. Do you have some other background process that's generating post records that might be confusing it?

Thanks for your comment. The speed has been manageable since the Nginx helper plugin was disabled. Unfortunately the issue has come back and haunt me. Apparently the nginx helper wasn't the root cause. I did few rounds of test by opening 5 different code snippets I have in new tabs (with default wordpress theme and all other plugins disabled). There will always be 1 or 2 out of 5 that encountered 522. While opening the snippets, I also monitored the resource usage via htop and they did not reach 100% for once.
Where do you think the bottleneck is? MySQL database or Nginx?

:-/ I don't know, sorry. I guess you need to trace out what it's doing when it's timing out. I agree I'd expect to see high resource usage in either the app or the database when that's happening.

There's no chance there's a sleep in the code somewhere, in a loop you're hitting? I can't imagine why there would be though. Or a blocking HTTP request to some other system, or an off-machine cache that's slow to respond or timing out?

Thanks for your help again. I ended up creating a new droplet in the Digital Ocean and migrated the whole whole Wordpress over using All-in-one Migration plugin. Everything is back to normal. I didn't even change the default memory limit in both php.ini and wp-config.php. Everything seems smooth. Perhaps something was wrong with my previous hosting setup after many rounds of tweaking by me...
